# Can't get mod_wsgi and Apache with Django to work

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

This is the error I get in my Apache error log:

`[Sun Aug 22 16:52:06 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named settings`

This is my .wsgi file, per [this blog post](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html):

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/wot/django-projects/aedo')
import settings
import django.core.management
django.core.management.setup_environ(settings)
utility = django.core.management.ManagementUtility()
command = utility.fetch_command('runserver')
command.validate()
import django.conf
import django.utils

django.utils.translation.activate(django.conf.settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I've double and triple checked the path name, and that is indeed the path to my project file. I've been trying to get this to work for hours, and have done much googling. I'm asking here as my last resort. I'm desperate!

EDIT: I'm aware that there are similar questions here on SA, and I've read through most all of them, to no avail

Comment: There's a fair chance that Django can find your settings file, but it cannot import it. Django gives this error whenever it can't import a settings file for whatever reason. So try adding an `import settings` in your `.wsgi` file.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you didn't make a typo in the path or anything? And you do actually have a `settings.py` in the `/home/wot/django-projects/aedo` directory? One or the other has to be false.

Comment: He does have 'import settings' in his WSGI file already. He isn't relying on DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable method.

Comment: Try typing the first three lines from the above into the python interpreter on the console.  Does it work?

Comment: If doing a test with command line Python, you need to be doing it as Apache user, ensuring that personal user environment, eg PYTHONPATH variables etc, aren't being inherited across a sudo. You also should do it while current working directory is '/'. This better approximates what happens under Apache.

Comment: @ars, I just tried running the first three lines and it worked fine.
@Graham, I tried to su into the apache user to try it, but I get "This account is currently not available."

Comment: So I had django.wsgi in /etc/httpd/wsgi because SELinux wasn't letting httpd access it in my home directory, so I turned selinux off, put it in my home directory, and modified the permissions and now it works. I'm not sure why having it in that other directory caused that error though? Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the output from running:

```
ls -las /home/wot/django-projects/aedo/
```

Is the directory and all the files readable to user that Apache runs as? If they aren't you  may get that error.

Also watch talk and look at slides mentioned at:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/sydney-pycon-modwsgi-talk-slides.html

as it discusses permissions issues further.

Comment: Yeah all the files are readable and executable to all users. And thanks will do

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work when you put:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/django')    # obs: path to django
sys.path.append('/home/wot/django-projects/aedo')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

in your django.wsgi file?

Comment: That wouldn't work as you added the site directory to sys.path and not the parent directory.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton - true, corrected. It's because I copied from one of my projects using pydev and usually I have 2 times the directory (1 for project name and 1 for src) like `.../django-projects/aedo/aedo/files.py`

Answer (score 2):

try changing

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'aedo.settings'
```

to

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

Actually I was getting this error too and I did the above. I also changed

```
ROOT_URLCONF =  'appname.urls'
```

to

```
ROOT_URLCONF =  'urls'
```

I hope your settings.py is in the same directory as the wsgi file for this project.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had weird import issues, Python claimed Django could not import Site... Because my install went from a purely "python runserver..." to a WSGI environment, the permissions was actually a problem.

Surprised as I didn't even change the permission on the django.contrib.site package, just all of the project's files to 755.